# Property of norm

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and let $C(X)$ denote the set of continuous complex valued functions on $X$.
Define $$ \|f\|:=\sup\{|f(x)|:x\in X\},$$

then prove that $\|fg\|\leq \|f\|\|g\|$.

Comment: What are you struggling with? Do you understand the definition of the norm?

Comment: yes i know the definition but i do not know  why it is inequality,it should be equality.But now i understand that how this is inequality.Thanks to everyone.

Comment: In future, you should include such concerns in the post so people can address them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every $x \in X $ we have $|g(x)| \leq \sup_{z \in X} |g(z)|$ by definition of the supremum, so for every $x \in X$ we may observe that
$$|f(x)g(x)| = |f(x)||g(x)|\leq |f(x)|\left(\sup_{z \in X}|g(z)|\right) =|f(x)|\|g\|,$$
Since this is true for every $x\in X$ we may take the supremum on both sides of the equation to get
$$\|fg\| = \sup_{x \in X}|f(x)g(x)| \leq \sup_{x \in X} |f(x)|\|g\| = \|f\|\|g\|$$

Comment: yes perfect.Thanx

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, as $\{(x,x)| x\in X\} \subset \{(x,y)| x,y\in X\}$:
$$
\sup_{x\in X} |f(x)g(x)| \le \sup_{x,y\in X} |f(x)g(y)|
= \sup_{x\in X}|f(x)| \sup_{y\in X}|g(y)|
$$

Comment: How do you justify $\sup_{x \in X} |f(x)g(x)| \leq \sup_{x,y \in X} |f(x)g(y)|$ ?

Comment: this is because $\{(x,x) | x\in X\}\subset X\times X$.

Comment: ok, it is really alternative then :).

Answer (score 2):

For all $x \in X$ we have
$$|f(x)| \leq \|f\| ,$$
as well as
$$|g(x)| \leq \|g\|. $$
Multiplying the two inequalities gives

$$|f(x)g(x)| \leq \|f\|\|g\| \; \forall x \in X .$$

Thus $\|f\| \|g\|$ is *an* upper bound of the set $\{|f(x)g(x)|:x \in X\}$, hence the *least* upper bound can't be larger.